# Postgres psql requires " FROM database.table" in sql statement

Tags: mysql, postgresql, windows

As a beginning learner of of Postgres I have created two different installations of a database where one requires a select statement to use `...FROM database.table...` and the other only requires `...FROM table...`. This was discovered in a Symfony project that could point to either installation. The project fails when pointing to the installation requiring `...FROM database.table...` How can the requirement to include the database name with a table name be removed, and where might that requirement have come from?

Background:
The project began with a MySQL database. Since I wanted to learn Postgres I followed some great material found online to convert a MySQL database to Postgres. The MySQL data was in Windows, Postgres was installed on an Ubuntu 18 VM. (The conversion created the Postgres version on the VM.) The VM's database was dumped with `pg_dump`, the resulting sql file copied to Windows and restored there. All of this in MySQL 8 & Postgres 12.

When the Symfony project points to the VM's database, all is fine and dandy. Pointing to the Windows copy fails because it cannot find any given table.

On the VM I can use `psql` to query using `...FROM table...`. In Windows with `psql`, even though `SELECT current_database();` returns the name of the database, I must use `...FROM database.table...` in a query.

Comment: Note that in `from database.table` "database" actually refers to a **schema** not a database. Those are two different things in Postgres (unlike MySQL which only has schemas, but calls them database)

Comment: @mustaccio In the sense that it answers the Why, perhaps. If "foreign" means not on localhost, then no  because the failure occurs when connecting to the local instance. Since the local instance was created by a dump of a foreign instance, does the fact of its foreign origin become a property of the local instance? (Hope that makes some sense!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ....FROM database.table
> ```

That is not a database, that is a schema.  (With the weird and confusing name of "database").

You can refer to things with 3 name components, `databasename.schemaname.tablename`, but this is rarely done as then the first component must be the same as the name of the database you are connected to.  Which makes it pretty useless, other than as a way to maintain compatibility with other database software.

In one database, your tables are in a schema which is in the search_path, and in the other database they are not.  Maybe that is because the search_path differs between databases, or maybe because the tables are actually in differently named schemas.  You can use `show search_path` to see what search_path is in effect in each database.

Comment: `show search_path` results are identical for Windows & VM: `"$user", public`. In Windows, pgAdmin4 shows the public schema has no tables, the `rv` schema (the one in question and my name for the database) shows 4 tables. I do not know how to get the same data for the VM installation, but I suspect it will be different. How significant is the above result and does it suggest a course of action?

Comment: I should also make clear that there is no possible way to change the project's sql statements to use `schema.table` instead of `table`. The project uses Doctrine's ORM. The net effect is that the code is independent of the DBMS.

Comment: You should be able to connect to pgAdmin4 to your VM installation, if you can't you might want to solve that problem as well. (Probably through a separate question describing the error message)

Comment: So now I'm guessing your postgreSQL user name is `rv` on the VM, but not on Windows.  So while search_path is the same, it is interpreted differently as "$user" gets substituted with a different value in each.

Comment: As it turns out, the Windows (inaccessible) rv is owned by `postgres`, the VM (accessible) is owned by `george`, i.e., me. I have connected pgAdmin4 to the VM.

Answer (score 1):

You should set your `search_path` appropriately:

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name SET search_path = database,public;
```

Here, `database` is the schema name from your question.

Then reconnect, and you should not need to qualify the table names with the schema.

Comment: It's taken me a while to understand and appreciate what has been said here. Changing the search path is indeed the proper fix.

Answer (score 0):

I found [the fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280032/how-do-i-specify-which-schema-to-use-for-doctrine-2-2-symfony-2-2-and-postgres) but not the reason why it's necessary.

For each entity in the project (Symfony 5.2), add the annotation `@ORM\Table(schema="rv")`. This forces the use of a specific schema. The good news is that the added annotation does not affect pointing the project to a MySQL database/schema.

Edit:
While this does not explain why `FROM schema.table` is required I do now know how to make the Windows instance NOT require `schema.table`. Instead of running the sql file created by `pg_dump` I  first deleted then recreated the `rv`, then used `pgloader` (at the VM) to migrate the MySQL database to the new Postgres `rv` database. The project then works without the `@ORM\Table(schema='...")` annotation.

With Symfony & Doctrine, if the console command `doctrine:database:create` is used for a Postgres project, any query will not `schema.table` and the annotation will also not be required.

Whew!